# System.Net.Http.HttpClient instance throws an exception when setting a comma. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

Given the following `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` `Portable Class Library` throws an exception:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "aaaa,bbbb");
```

The exception is: **Invalid Format**

> at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddInternal (System.String
>   name, IEnumerable`1 values, System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderInfo
>   headerInfo, Boolean ignoreInvalid) [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.Headers/HttpHeaders.cs:195
>   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name,
>   IEnumerable`1 values) [0x00011] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.Headers/HttpHeaders.cs:170
>   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name,
>   System.String value) [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.Headers/HttpHeaders
>   < ... snip ...>

Now this only happens under the following

Header key = `Authorization`. If you change that to anything else, it's ok.
Value = has to have a comma, in it.

Now, this previous SO question suggests that a comma is the correct way to stick multiple values in the header.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

NOTE: This is on Xamarin, so I guess it's mono. Not sure if that's important.

UPDATE:

here's a pic of it.

[image]

Comment: The exception states it is an invalid format. Why are you trying to set a comma in that header?

Comment: @CodeCaster because I want to and believe/believed it was valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this links spec rfc2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) separating with a comma does seem valid.

"It uses an extensible, case-insensitive token to identify the authentication scheme,
   followed by a comma-separated list of attribute-value pairs which
   carry the parameters necessary for achieving authentication via that
   scheme."

But therein it suggests you are quite possible setting them incorrectly, they must be of the form "attribute-value pairs":

```
auth-param     = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )
```

How exactly are you setting them?

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "aaaa,bbbb");
```

The above is seemingly invalid, they are not attribute pairs "aaaa,bbbb". There is no = sign for either attribute you are attempting to set.

Try the following as a test:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "aaaa=1234,bbbb=45678");
```

Comment: But the value i want to set for the Authorization field is 'aaa,bbb' .. not a key/value result. Then, only my server, i split that *value* by comma and assume the first segment is Foo and the second segment is Bah.

Comment: Well you can't, you'll have to think of something else. Perhaps you can base64-encode the value.

Comment: Is this just for the AUTHORIZATION header? or -any- header?

Comment: If you want to have a header of the format you specify then create a custom header, but there is cache control issue with that approach, or just put some dummy data to make it a key value pair, e.g. 1=aaaa, 2=bbbb

Comment: @Pure.Krome The auth parameter can either be name/value pairs or it can be a token68 value of which comma is not a valid character.  See here http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-26#section-2.1

Comment: @DarrelMiller Is that draft that is dated February 2014 in force yet?

Comment: @PaulZahra The drafts have been approved for publication and should be RFCs shortly. http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/wiki

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the mono implementation that did not allow valid characters in headers, i.e. `[` and `]` - this has been fixed, but for Xamarin Android it has not reached stable branch yet (it will come with Xamarin Android 5)

It is possible to circumvent this, if you cannot wait, you need to ship now, and you NEED to have special characters in the header, there is a way (I have now disclaimered away)

Before adding the headers you can add the characters as allowed tokens in headers. This is undocumented, illegal (from a proper coding perspective) and done via reflection, but it works:

```
var assembly = typeof(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders).Assembly;
var lexer = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Http.Headers.Lexer");
var field = lexer.GetField("token_chars", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var tokens = ( bool[])field.GetValue(null);
tokens[91] = true;
tokens[93] = true;
field.SetValue(null, tokens);
```

In the sample above we allow character 91 and 93 [ and ] respectively.

Comment: Please notice that on newer Android that have the updated Mono (Version 5) the above code will fail. It is no longer needed. If you do need to support older Mono frameworks, make a test for version >5 before using the answer.